# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch after vectorizing a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization, edge-detection

I tried turning this:

```
for r=1:fsize
     for c=1:fsize
         mask(r,c) = exp(-(((r-centre)^2+(c-centre)^2)/2*(sigma^2)));
     end
 end
```

into

```
mask(1:fsize,1:fsize) = exp(-(((1-centre:fsize-centre).^2.+(1-centre:fsize-centre).^2)./2.*(sigma.^2)));
```

but I now get the error "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch".

My understanding is that this has something to do with the indexing in the two arrays not being matched, but that doesn't seem to be the case here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `meshgrid` for that,

```
[r c]=meshgrid(1:fsize);
mask = exp(-(((r-centre).^2+(c-centre).^2)/2*(sigma^2)));
```

this assumes that `centre` and `sigma` are scalars.

Comment: +1 You could save some time by moving some operations within `meshgrid`: `[r c]=meshgrid(((1:fsize)-centre).^2); mask = exp(-(r+c)/2*(sigma^2))`;